# IPhone - UITableView reloadData + back to the first result

Tags: iphone, uitableview

is there a way to for a UITableView to show the begin of the results using reloadData instead of showing the same position as before it's called?

Code:

```
-(void)orderResult{
    FMDatabase *db = [DatabaseManager openDatabase:@QRDATABASE];
    NSString *queryCounter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select count(*) as count from %@", self.appDelegate.query];
    FMResultSet *rsCount = [db executeQuery:queryCounter];
    [rsCount next];
    self.rowCounter = [rsCount intForColumn:@"count"];

    if (([rule isEqualToString:@""] )|| (rule == nil)) {
        rule = @"dist";
    }

    NSLog(@"initWithStyle: self.rowCounter = %i", self.rowCounter);

    FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:queryTest];

    results = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    while ([rs next]){
        NSMutableArray *aRS = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [aRS addObject:[rs stringForColumn:@"nome"]];

        [aRS addObject:[rs stringForColumn:@"dist"]];
        NSLog(@" while ([rs next]): %@ - %@",[aRS objectAtIndex:0], [aRS objectAtIndex:1]);

        [results addObject:aRS];
        [aRS release];
    }
    [db release];

}


-(IBAction)azOrg{
    NSLog(@"azOrg");
    rule = @"nome";
    [self orderResult];    
    [table reloadData];    
}
```

Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not by using `realodData` but you can by using `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` immediately afterwards.

```
-(IBAction)azOrg{
    NSLog(@"azOrg");
    rule = @"nome";
    [self orderResult];
    [table reloadData];
    [table scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]
                 atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop
                         animated:YES]; //Change to NO if you do not want it to animate
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do know about the sdk documentation, right?

Check out UITableView's - (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated method.